# Why is FAC 1 cycled OFF to ON during a dual engine failure?

Tags: airbus-a320, emergency-procedures

I was reading in the Airbus A320 FCTM regarding the dual engine failure procedure. The ECAM tells us to recycle FAC 1 OFF THEN ON. Why do we have to recycle FAC 1 specifically? I opened the QRH and it shows this also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Resetting FAC 1 enables the recovery of characteristics speed displayed on the PFD.
> - Resetting FAC 1 also enables rudder trim recovery, even if no indication is available.
> - When the hydraulic power is lost, the right aileron is lost, and is in the upfloat position.
> - Rudder trim may be used to compensate for this upfloating aileron.

This is from the QRH under 'ENG DUAL FAILURE'. That answers why FAC 1 is reset.

FAC 2 on the other hand (unlike FAC 1) is not powered by the emergency electric system, see § Flight Control System - Electrical Supply. And that's why you don't cycle FAC 2.

From the same section FAC 1 is not on a hot (stand by) supply, so after a power interruption it requires a reboot (my interpretation).

[image]
(Red highlight mine)

---

Do not use for flight.